# c++: задать точность числа при выводе через printf

Tags: c++, строки, printf, format, sprintf

Подскажите, как задать точность вывода `float`/`double` числа через `printf`?

У меня сейчас вывод выглядит следующим образом:

```
printf("a: %20.16f, b: %20.16f, c: %20.16f", a, b, c);
```

и настроен под точность `double`, но иногда я использую `float` числа (для ускорения расчётов) и тогда мне нужна `float` точность без вывода дополнительных чисел

Как корректнее реализовать выбор соответствующей точность?
Есть варианты

1) определять тип данных и для каждого типа использовать свой вариант вывода

```
template<class T>
void myprint()
{
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(float))
        printf("a: %10.6f, b: %10.6f, c: %10.6f", a, b, c);
    else
        printf("a: %20.16f, b: %20.16f, c: %20.16f", a, b, c);
}
```

2) формировать строку в зависимости от точности

```
const int prec = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 + 1;
const std::string format = "%" + std::to_string(4 + prec) + "." + std::to_string(prec);
...
```

оба варианта с недостатками (во втором как-то приходится правильно сформировать строку `$x.y`, что требует относительно много кода для такой задачи, а в первом варианте слишком много `if` придется наставить)

как можно оптимальнее разрешить эту проблему?

Comment: Поэтому потоки и манипуляторы лучше...

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, а можно поподробнее

Comment: Zhihar,  в вашем вопросе речь идет о printf, потому не могу в ответе написать.  Но в сайте есть уже ответы на этот вопрос. Поищите, найдете

Comment: 2-й вариант лучше, только (из-за С++) все как-то сложновато выглядит. Просто сформируйте нормальную сишную `char *` строку формата внутри  `#ifdef` обычным `sprintf`-ом и используйте ее далее.

Answer (score 2):

Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью специализации шаблона:

```
//общий шаблон из которого будет инстанцироваться float
template<class T>
void myprint()
{
    printf("a: %10.6f, b: %10.6f, c: %10.6f", a, b, c);
} 

//специализация для double
template<>
void myprint<double>()
{
    printf("a: %20.16f, b: %20.16f, c: %20.16f", a, b, c);
}
```

Также замечу, что printf - это функция языка Си, рекомендую воспользоваться функционалом языка C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<class T>
void myprint()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed
        << "a: " << std::setw(10) << std::setprecision(6) << a << ", "
        << "b: " << std::setw(10) << std::setprecision(6) << b << ", "
        << "c: " << std::setw(10) << std::setprecision(6) << c;
} 

template<>
void myprint<double>()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed
        << "a: " << std::setw(20) << std::setprecision(16) << a << ", "
        << "b: " << std::setw(20) << std::setprecision(16) << b << ", "
        << "c: " << std::setw(20) << std::setprecision(16) << c;
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли добавить отправку манипулятора fixed перед выводом чисел, так оно будет выводить в defaultfloat (аналог %g для printf).

Comment: согласен, поправил ответ